# How to access information from other sites based on specific parameters provided by a user to my website?

Tags: database, web, web-development-server

So I am currently working on this project and I am confused on how to tackle this issue I am having.

I am creating this website that will go behind the scenes and input the data the user is providing us with and checking to see availability on various websites. I am confused on how the logistics of this would work. Would it make more sense to use API's rather than create maybe a bot (I don't even know if this would work) or even if there was a way to code it in myself.

A similar platform to what the general idea behind what operations would be used is vaccines.gov where the system will display the availability of vaccines nearby (a value inputted by user is zipcode). I just need to be pushed in a general direction as I am unsure how to approach this.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends.  Do you have cooperation from these other sites? How easy is the data to find on the other sites?  Do the other sites allow the data to be crawled?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I requested permission to the API for one of the sites but I have't recieved it yet. I'm not sure about the sites allowing data to be crawled. How would I check that?